# ML heroku deployment

Tags: heroku

I get an error message when i try to push my heroku app. I have a runtime.txt with the text python-3.7.10, i have a requirements.txt, i have a Procfile and im not really sure what's missing. python 3.7.10 is a supported runtime. Can anyone help me, im really stuck. It keeps saying "Requested runtime (Python-3.7.10) is not available for this stack (heroku-20)". Thanks in advance!

```
<<-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
-----> Python app detected
-----> Using Python version specified in runtime.txt
 !     Requested runtime (Python-3.7.10) is not available for this stack (heroku-20).
 !     Aborting.  More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed>>
```

Comment: "python 3.7.10 is a supported runtime"—it is not. What makes you think that it is?

Answer (score 0):

[Heroku-20](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-20-stack) is the default stack for newly created apps: within this stack you can use different languages and versions.
In case of **Python** the supported versions are:

- python-3.9.7
- python-3.8.12
- python-3.7.12
- python-3.6.15

You `runtime.txt` sets `Python-3.7.10` which is not supported: correct the version or remove the file (relying on the default version python-3.9.7).